# What is the Curl while making a Post request into the Vision Api Product Search?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-product-search

I saw that they ask me To send your request, choose one of these options:
[image]

what are these options i didn't understand, i want only to make a post request like the first command with the json body as mentioned, but down in the curl i didn't understand what to do.

Comment: Please include in your question the URL of the page that you've screenshot.

Comment: The top part of the page describes the URL and the body of the request that you must send to Google to make the Vision API request. The bottom part of the page describes 2 alternatives for how you can make the call (described at the top). [`curl`](https://curl.se/) is one tool that can do this. The command shown is the `curl` command that will make the request to the Vision API. You need only update the command with your Project and Location IDs.

Comment: Check out: https://curlconverter.com/